# Read another's uncommitted session - temp table data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The thing is..

My sp throws error: string or binary data would be trunkated.

I traced down the code snippet with sql profiler to find the line where it occurs, however
I would need to get the data which is being inserted.

I added the code to insert that data to my temp table and thought that i would be able to 
read its content from another session (while that session is still in progress - not committed) and ...

unfortunately select statement hangs even with nolock hint... under not committed isolation level.

Generally I would like to get the data which will be rolledback because of the error.

Is it possible? How would i do it?

Comment: You are adding it in the transaction that's getting rolled back, so it gets rolled back. You could write it to a file, or email it maybe. Got me scratching my head a bit, should be the app that calls the SP that deals with this.

Answer (score 1):

Temp tables are session scoped. If you check `sys.tables` in tempdb, you will see that your #t table is actually caled something like

`#t__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000006`

So, you couldn't read it from another session.

What's more, temp tables don't survive a rollback of transaction. To be able to read the data after the rollback, use table variable, and after the rollback save it into a permanent table you can query.

Comment: I know it. If i create ## table or just select * into _temp table from .... - I cannot read it from another's session even with nolock statement. I need some solution which could save my data in spite of rolled back session or read data during open transaction ....

Comment: Sure, insert the data into table variable, rollback transaction, insert from table variable to a permanent table, and that's it.